# How to fetch new Records each time with the increement of 10 using sqlite?

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite, select

i have Table which contain the Name and URLS of images .

```
[db executeQuery:"drop table ImagesTable;"];
        [db executeQuery:"create table ImagesTable ('no' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'img_name' text, 'img_url' text);"];
```

Now i am fetching record like this way using limits

```
NSMutableArray *recordSet=[db getRecordSet:"select * from ImagesTable limit 0,10;"];
```

when the above 10 images gets download then i am deleting the above 10 records so that next time again i have fresh 10 records like this

```
NSString *sqlQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from ImagesTable where no=%d;",[[[imgArr objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];
                    [db executeQuery:(char *)[sqlQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [img release];
                     counter++;
```

Now my question is without deleting the records how can i get new records each time with the increament of 10. like below
Example:- 0 to 10,10 to 20, 20 to 30 and so on.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) explains what the first number after the LIMIT is for.

Use `LIMIT 0,10` for the first page, `LIMIT 10,10` for the second page, `LIMIT 20,10` for the third page, etc.

Comment: thanks for your response but i don't have fix records in table it will be dynamic then how can i write LIMIT 0,10, 10,10, 20,10 like this way?